# Qt QVarLengthArray of QString Internals

Tags: c++, c, arrays, qt

What is the internal data structure of a QVarLengthArray?

For example, if I where to have:

```
QVarLengthArray<QString> anArray;

QString string1 = "whatever";
QString string2 = "something else";

anArray[0] = string1;
anArray[1] = string2;
```

Is it easy to pre-calculate &anArray[1] given &anArray?

I have been traipsing through the QVarLengthArray source code trying to understand how QVarLengthArray stores an array of QStrings in memory.   As much as I like Qt, one thing that is particularly painful to me is its opaque pointer basis.   (The helper functions in the debugger help in some cases, but when really trying to dig into the internals, the opaque pointers obscure a great deal of information that would otherwise be available in the debugger.)

I found a couple "Qt Internals" articles on codeproject.com and elsewhere, but none helped.

In general, it would be great to have a way to peer into the real data structures behind the opaque pointers, but for the immediate need it would be great to understand if there is a good way to predict the start address of each element in the QVarLengthArray of MyClass which contains pointers, QStrings, and integers.

(Having this information will help simplify a custom serialization.  I do understand the risks to reusability and am willing to accept those risks for this experiment.)

Comment: So what is your question...?

Comment: Primary question is what is the internal data structure of QVarLengthArray<MyClass>  where MyClass contains QStrings.

Comment: It would also be great to know how to view the real data structures behind Qt's opaque pointers in the debugger (in my case gdb within Creator).

Comment: I see your point though.   I will edit the original post to make the question more clear.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I made an edit to the original question that I believe will make the question more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look under the "private" section of the class headers to find the member variables -- these will tell you the class structure. Here's a link to the first member of QVarLengthArray: http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qvarlengtharray.h.html#QVarLengthArray::a

In Qt 5, a QVarLengthArray starts with 2 ints, followed by a pointer to the first element in the array, followed by a union which holds the actual array itself, preallocated on the stack.

If your array size is less than or equal to the preallocated capacity, then `&(array[1])` is simply a fixed number of bytes after `&anArray`. However, if your array grows bigger than the preallocated capacity, then QVarLengthArray will switch to the heap instead. When this happens, there is no longer any relationship between `&(array[1])` and `&anArray`.

If you have `&anArray`, a robust way to find `&(anArray[1])` is as follows:

```
QString* anArray_0 = (&anArray)->begin(); // &(anArray[0])
QString* anArray_1 = anArray_0 + 1; // &(anArray[1])
```

Or, to do it the low-level way without calling any member functions (assuming there's no padding):

```
// Use reinterpret_cast to enable 1-byte pointer arithmetic
char* outerPtr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&anArray);

QString* anArray_0 = reinterpret_cast<QString*>( outerPtr + 2*sizeOf(int) ); // &(anArray[0])
QString* anArray_1 = anArray_0 + 1; // &(anArray[1])
```

> (Having this information will help simplify a custom serialization. I do understand the risks to reusability and am willing to accept those risks for this experiment.)

Qt promises source- and binary-compatibility across minor releases. The structure of QVarLengthArray is guaranteed to remain unchanged until Qt 6, at least.

> In general, it would be great to have a way to peer into the real data structures behind the opaque pointers

I find the [Woboq Code Browser](http://code.woboq.org/) very useful for this -- the source code becomes an interactive web of hyperlinks, and you can search for any class in the library. Just look in the class header to find the opaque pointer, and click on it.